# qemu-system-x86_64.exe is not responding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

I just installed Android Studio and I've been trying to figure out for the past 3 hours why it is that when I try to run my newly created project on a emulated phone it doesn't work.

It's not even that the program doesn't work; it's that it freezes the moment I open it. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling [HAXM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Accelerator), SDKs for the phone, and recreating the phone / wiping the data on the phone and retrying, and nothing's worked so far.

What causes this problem? Please see the picture to see what the problem is.

P.S.: I'm using Android Studio on Windows. My system is beefy and should be able to run the emulator fine. I have *Virtualization Enabled* too.

[image: Emulator broken window]

[image: Not responding window]

Answer (score 1):

This helps me in getting it to work: switch off [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) on Windows:

Open a PowerShell window as *Administrator* and run:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Reboot afterwards. Alternatively, run 'optionalfeatures' and select the hypervisor platform to remove. To test if it really worked, run:

```
emulator.exe -verbose -avd <YOUR AVD NAME>
```

You can list the [AVDs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) with 'emulator.exe -list-avds'.

It is not my credits, but those of 'viet-quocnguyen'. See *[Android emulator not starting anymore #6471](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6471#issuecomment-770417782)*

Comment: I need HyperV on my windows, Did you have any other solution?

Comment: It seems to be fixed (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202188690?pli=1) as mentioned in the thread with the original solution (see link above). I haven't researched any further as I don't need HyperV. Good luck!