# Visual Studio 2022 qemu-system is not responding

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, qemu, android-device-manager

I have Visual Studio 2022 and have installed some Android SDK like below (in PowerShell):

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\7.0\bin"
.\sdkmanager.bat --list_installed
```

Output:

```
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
  Path                                                  | Version      | Description                                     | Location
  -------                                               | -------      | -------                                         | -------
  build-tools;32.0.0                                    | 32.0.0       | Android SDK Build-Tools 32                      | build-tools\32.0.0
  build-tools;33.0.0                                    | 33.0.0       | Android SDK Build-Tools 33                      | build-tools\33.0.0
  emulator                                              | 31.3.14      | Android Emulator                                | emulator
  extras;android;m2repository                           | 47.0.0       | Android Support Repository                      | extras\android\m2repository
  extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager   | 7.6.5        | Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) | extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
  ndk-bundle                                            | 20.1.5948944 | NDK                                             | ndk-bundle
  patcher;v4                                            | 1            | SDK Patch Applier v4                            | patcher\v4
  platform-tools                                        | 33.0.2       | Android SDK Platform-Tools 33.0.2               | platform-tools
  platforms;android-28                                  | 6            | Android SDK Platform 28, rev 6                  | platforms\android-28
  platforms;android-29                                  | 5            | Android SDK Platform 29, rev 5                  | platforms\android-29
  platforms;android-31                                  | 1            | Android SDK Platform 31                         | platforms\android-31
  platforms;android-33                                  | 1            | Android SDK Platform 33                         | platforms\android-33
  system-images;android-28;default;x86_64               | 4            | Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image                  | system-images\android-28\default\x86_64
  system-images;android-29;default;x86_64               | 8            | Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image                  | system-images\android-29\default\x86_64
  system-images;android-31;default;arm64-v8a            | 3            | ARM 64 v8a System Image                         | system-images\android-31\default\arm64-v8a
  system-images;android-31;default;x86_64               | 3            | Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image                  | system-images\android-31\default\x86_64
  system-images;android-31;google_apis_playstore;x86_64 | 9            | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image      | system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
  system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64           | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image      | system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64
```

And my Android Device Manager like below:

[image]

But my problem is as you can see in *[qemu-system-x86_64.exe is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914500/qemu-system-x86-64-exe-is-not-responding)*, when I try to start one of Android devices, my qemu-system is ***not responding***, and I do not know how to resolve this problem

**Note:**

As you can see in *[qemu-system-x86_64.exe is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914500/qemu-system-x86-64-exe-is-not-responding/69789845#69789845)*, [michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804509/michael) says, for resolving this issue, I must disable [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), but I need Hyper-V, and I can not disable it, so I can not try michael's solution. Is there a solution that works alongside of Hyper-V?

Sometimes with Android Device Manager, I get the below errors:

```
Device error: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=5cd6ab71-b279-40b1-b2d0-f506a0f87649'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
WARNING | ** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.**
```

I run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel` and the below log is printed:

```
accel:
0
Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.WHPX (10.0.22621) is installed and usable.
accel
```

And my `systeminfo` is like below:

```
cd C:\Users\sooro
systeminfo
```

Output:

```
Host Name:                 SSOROOSH-PC
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                00331-10000-00001-AA598
Original Install Date:     11/10/2022, 12:10:44 AM
System Boot Time:          12/22/2022, 11:01:09 AM
System Manufacturer:       ASUS
System Model:              System Product Name
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 151 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~3400 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 1720, 8/12/2022
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume13
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
```

I need Hyper-V on my system. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/74375285/1539100

Comment: You can check the [Android emulator troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows) for more information.

Comment: I update my question with additional info and add my question in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/qemu-system-not-responding/10233039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in *[QEMU system is not responding](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/qemu-system-not-responding/10233039#T-N10258374)*, Microsoft says this is a *bug*, and it is fixed internally, and pending release.